# How can I call a native mobile API in Construct 2?

Tags: javascript, html5, mobile, construct-2

How can I use mobile API features in a Construct 2 game (HTML 5/JavaScrit engine)?

I didn't find anything about that on the net, unlike other game frameworks like Corona Enterprise or Cocos2d.

Comment: There are objects in Construct 2 which offer some specific API features of the services/OSs you can deploy. These objects can be added to your project. if your question is about using HTML5/JS scripts in C2, you can browse the web archives [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910190325/https://www.scirra.com/forum/extending-construct-2_f150?sid=04080f153f8f7940445939647640abd7).